# How do I open a .tsv file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

For a class, we were given in .tsv format to work with. I'm in a beginner data science class so I'm not familiar with data (and most of what there is to Python, honestly) that comes in this form.

My group mate gave me the following code to work with, saying it worked for him. I tried it (along with other lines of code I found online), but none of them work.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.tsv', sep='\t',engine="python", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

This is what comes out:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-715b8f905054> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('name.tsv', sep='\t',engine="python",  quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

NameError: name 'csv' is not defined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: having `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` is the problem

Comment: Your friend forgot to mention that they have the line `import csv` at the top of their script.

Comment: It says name `csv` is not defined. Import it.

Comment: Anyway, `.tsv` is just a way to say that  it's a **tab**-separated values file. So if you opened up the file, you'd see that a tab separates fields as opposed to say a csv (**comma**-separated values) where a comma distinguishes between fields. You might even come across a `.psv` **pipe**-separated values (`|`). They're all just simple plain text files, the extension is more for documenting the delimeter.

Comment: just do `df = pd.read_csv('file.tsv', sep='\t')`

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. Thanks for the swift response! I've been going over this for almost an hour.

Comment: @JacekRojek: The comment from ALollz and Vikash above worked for me. When I did that code earlier, it also didn't work. Error message showed something about ut-8.

Comment: @ALollz: Thanks for the explanation, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the csv library? Notice the 'import' in my sample code below. Your line does look correct.

```
 >>> df.to_csv('foo.txt',index=False,header=False)
 >>> !cat foo.txt
123,"this is ""out text"""
>>> import csv
>>> df.to_csv('foo.txt',index=False,header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
>>> !cat foo.txt
123,this is "out text"
```